# Alias "/var/run/syslog" to "/dev/log" on MacOS 13

Tags: macos, syslog

I need to run software that uses "/dev/log" on MacOS. I know I can run it if I rewrite it "/var/run/syslog" but the problem is I cannot change the source code. How can I create an alias "/dev/log" points "/var/run/syslog" on my Mac? I am using MacOS venture 13.1

Comment: Source code can *always* be changed in programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I don't have a Mac to personally test this on, I believe you could accomplish this by creating a symbolic link from what your software is expecting to the socket your Mac uses:

```bash
ln -s /var/run/syslog /dev/log
```

Creating a test link on a Linux system this way allows me to send logs that show up in the system log. You could test this approach yourself using something like this (assuming you have a `logger` utility):

```bash
ln -s /var/run/syslog my-test-link
logger -u my-test-link "test my custom link"
# check your log to make sure that your test message made it through
```